# Distance covered in Premier League

Tags: football, statistics, english-premier-league

Where can I find the distance covered by players in the Premier League and the other 5 big leagues? I know you can find the ones for the Champions League on UEFA's site but I can't seem to find it for these leagues.

Answer (score 2):

The distance covered by players can be calculated from the data via the performance data feeds provided by [Opta](http://www.optasports.com/services/media/data-feeds/performance-data-feeds.aspx), however these are commercial and would require some form of payment to access them.